# How to Set Column Heights - Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am playing around with bootstrap 4 and I am not sure how to get my heights correctly. I have a "side nav", "header", "main" and "footer".

I want "main" to take up most of the height. However for some reason my heights must be messed up as the side nave does not go all the way down and I got this white chunk in the bottom left hand corner.

If you do full screen on my code you will see it.

```css
body,
html,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -80px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper h-100">
    <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li>
          <a>
                        Home
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: red;">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <main class="col-12 h-100" style="background-color: yellow;">
          test
        </main>
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: pink;">
          test2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem currently is the that using `h-100` on the `row`, makes the child `col-12` also set to `h-100` exceed the viewport height which causes scrolling and the whitespace under the sidebar.

As of **Bootstrap 4.1**, there is a `flex-fill` util class that is helpful for this layout...

```
.flex-fill {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

In this case, you can use it so that the child divs grow to fill remaining height. Just set min-height on the `.wrapper`:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

And then, make `container-fluid` also a flexbox container (using `d-flex`). Use the util `flex-fill` to make `row` and the middle `col-12` fill height:

```
<div class="wrapper d-flex">
    <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li>
                <a>
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row flex-fill flex-column">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: red;">
                One of three columns
            </div>
            <main class="col-12 flex-fill" style="background-color: yellow;">
                test
            </main>
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: pink;">
                test2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VvogWj44cS

Comment: Ah, ic the only thing though is that this does not work in IE 11.

Comment: It also does not seem to work in Edge 16, nor firefox

Comment: It seems to have something to do with d-flex